# How to convert a kivy file with windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, converters, kivy-language

how can I convert python and kivy file (.kv) into android app, using windows?
I've tried(*) but it converted only the python script, how can I convert also the kv file with the main python file?

- --> I tried to convert to .exe my scripts because I didn't understood how to convert to apk,
  I used:

python -m PyInstaller --name touchtracer Desktop\touchtracer\main.py

(adding to the touchtracer.spec the following:)
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew

and a code in
https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html
that I can't write here because it make an error

then:
python -m PyInstaller touchtracer.spec

and it worked, but it converted only the main python script with part of the program and not also the kivy file with graphic and other things.

Now what can I do to convert it to .apk or .exe?

-Thanks

Comment: You mean convert your app into an .exe ?

Comment: convert to what? wich format?

Comment: You said "I've tried", but what did you try?

Comment: i am not sure you have gone through the documentation, tools like buildozer and python-for-android are there for this purpose.

Comment: In your touchracer.spec file, you can add a 'datas' element in the Analysis object to list things like .kv files, images, etc. that are used by your app. Check this website for details: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are trying to create an apk for android with windows, then you have to install any [VM](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj3-4fmmpjuAhXUc30KHRnbDGIQFjAKegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FVirtual_machine&usg=AOvVaw2Nr2B-KSaouxDqBPkXo1ls) like [VIRTUAL BOX](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and use LINUX because, as per Kivy's official docs, only linux is capable of debugging kivy scripts to apk. Or you can use GOOGLE COLAB
2. If you are trying to create an .exe file, then you can use [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think buildozer VM is the best way to build apk.

Buildozer VM:
https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android-vm.html

To build apk package:
https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html

well if you are not looking for above mentioned, then you may try your luck integrating KV code into python by using, not sure if apk can be built from windows.

### you may use below format inside .py file

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
##kv code here
''')
```